# How can I prove two cochain complexes have the same cohomology groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Given two cochain compleesx $(C, d_1)$ and $(D, d_2)$ and a morphism between them $f: C\to D$. Is there any criterion that could allow me to prove $H^n(C)=H^n(D)$ for all $n$, i.e. the cohomology group of $C$ and $D$ are the same.

I know that if these two chains are homotpic equivalent, which means there is some $g: D\to C$ such that $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are chain homotopic to the identity maps, we get the results. But this should be stronger than what I want. So I am just wondering if there is some "if and only if criterion" on when two chains have the same cohomology groups.

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'quasi-isomorphism' but what you want is essentially its definition, so, this might not be useful. There is a [somewhat relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053387) (no answers though) which asks when quasi-iso is a chain homotopy equivalence. This [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59390) is linked there (not entirely related but might be helpful).